# Array map function renders correct but calls function with last element rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the map function to iterate through a JSON Array which looks similar to this

```
table=[
  {"name":"jon snow",
  "house":"stark"
  },
  {
  "name":"arya",
  "house":"stark"
  },
  {"name":"cersei",
  "house":"lannister"
  }
]
```

Map function renders the items perfectly however, the onClick handler seems to pass only the last item of the array.

For example, the text items are rendered to display the appropriate name, however, on clicking their individual action button seems to pass only the last element.

Here, after triggering the event handler "handleClose", I logged the "item" element printed to the console but it displays element with name "cersei" even on clicking the element with name "jon snow".

The syntax seems to be fine for the event handler for React afaik. And, since the variable "item" is also local variable within the function. It shouldn't display the last item in the array. Is there anything I am missing over here?

```
{/*Event Handler*/}
function handleClose(item) {
  console.log(item)
  setAnchorEl(null);
}

{/*Few lines of code after in the return function of React*/}
 var table2=[
      {"name":"jon snow",
      "house":"stark"
      },
      {"name":"arya",
      "house":"stark"
      },
      {"name":"cersei",
      "house":"lannister"
      }
      ]
    console.log(table);
   return(
  <div>
      <div>

      </div>

      {/*Actual table data*/}
      <div>
      <Card style={{width:'100%'}}>
       <Card.Body>
       <div >
    {table2.map((item,index)=>{

      let tempElement =item;
        return(
            <div >

    <Grid container spacing={0}>
    <Grid item xs={2} >
        <div style={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
            <ListItem alignItems="flex-start">
                <ListItemAvatar>
                <Avatar src={item.picture} />
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText style={{wordBreak:'normal'}}
                primary={item.name}
                secondary={
                    <React.Fragment>
                    <Typography
                        component="span"
                        variant="body2"
                        className={classes.inline}
                        color="textPrimary"
                    >
                    {getRoleFromData(item.roles)}
                    </Typography>

                    </React.Fragment>
                }
                />
            </ListItem>
        </div>

    </Grid>

    {/*View/Edit buttons */}
    <Grid item xs style={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}} >
    <div>  
            <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>Action</Button>
     <ThemeProvider>
     <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem><Button onClick={()=>handleClose(item)}>View</Button></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem><Button onClick={()=>handleClose(item)}>Edit</Button></MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </ThemeProvider>
     </div>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
<div>
<Divider variant="inset"/>               
</div> 
</div>
        );

    })
    }
    </div>
       </Card.Body>
   </Card>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you make it onClick={(item)=>handleClose(item)} then does it work?

Comment: No, that did not work